# Add ACCESSKEY to rows in APEX report

Tags: jquery, oracle, oracle-apex

Is there a way to add accesskey for numbers 1-9 to the first 9 rows in an APEX report using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it using jQuery in the "Execute When Page Loads" section of the "Edit Page" page:

First, you have to declare a variable in the "Function and Global Variable Declaration" section. I named mine `keyNum` and set it to `1`.

Next, use that variable in the "Execute When Page Loads" section like so:

```
$('a[href=(enter your href here)').each(function() {
   if(keyNum < 10)
   {
      $(this).attr('accesskey',keyNum++);
   }
});
```